# spring annotation not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I am starting with Spring Framework and want to do a HelloWorld with annotatios, I've made it work creating a controller and a view, basic hello work I guess; however, I want to use annotatios since I can not use SimpleFormController any more (deprecated).

The error I am getting is Estado HTTP 404 - /av/index.jsp

I am using Netbeans and I am basing the example on the basic template It provides. I have the following files, I am pretty sure it is a missconfiguration but I can't find anything that would help me so far. Thanks in advance.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

    <bean id="annotationHandlerMapping" 
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
        <property name="order" value="1"/>
        <property name="alwaysUseFullPath" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="controller"/>

</beans>
```

indexController.java

```
package controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/index.do", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView inicio (){
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("index");
        mv.addObject("usuario", "jaxkodex");
        return mv;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have conflict between request mapping and servlet mapping. In your case you would need to access your url with `/index.do.do`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

in your config `dispatcher-servlet.xml`

See [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) for more info

Answer (score 1):

You mapped the path `/index.do` in your controller, so you have to access it with the following url: `http://localhost/av/index.do`

Comment: I don't understand. Did it work? My advice for the simplest way to get to a working Spring MVC App: Install [Spring Tool Suite IDE](http://www.springsource.org/sts) and create a Spring Template Project of Type MVC.

Answer (score 1):

`<mvc:annotation-driven/>` will solve out your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
<bean 
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"/>
```

add an entry in dispatcher-servlet.xml

Answer (score 0):

in your disapatcher-servlet.xml, add
    `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` to enable annotation driven handler mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Try to go through one of my tutorials:

Creation of a [simple Controller](http://fruzenshtein.com/spring-mvc-creation-of-simple-controller-with-java-based-config/) with java-based config

I hope I will get success with it